# How to remap my Backspace to a 'd' while in Visual Mode with Vintage in Sublime

Tags: vim, sublimetext3, keymapping

While in visual mode with if you highlight some text and press <kbd>backspace</kbd> the cursor will continue to move back and continue to highlight more of your code; however, if you hit the <kbd>d</kbd> key, the highlighted text will be deleted and sublime will move back into command mode.

I'd like my <kbd>backspace</kbd> key to be mapped to my <kbd>d</kbd> key but only when I'm in visual mode. But I think that it's more like I'd like to map my <kbd>backspace</kbd> key to the same command as my <kbd>d</kbd> key when I'm in visual mode (because I think that's how sublime goes about emulating vim anyways, but not completely sure) How would I go about doing this? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
{ "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "set_action", "args": {
    "action": "vi_delete",
    "description": "Delete"},
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

This is where I got the relevant information to work on. [Default sublime keymap in vintage mode](https://gist.github.com/alloy-d/2911127)

Comment: @mbigras: I just learned that it is not a good idea to put thank you comments. I've added a link to my answer. It might help in adding more mappings

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sublime configuration, but from vim's point of view you can do this:

```
vnoremap <bs> d
```